# Wordpress - email specific custom fields + user information

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress: 3.4.1

I am looking at achieving the following.

Use a plugin or anything else available that, can pull particular custom fields from a psot and send a email to a user, containnig those custom fields and name + surname of current user

Any ideas.....

Thanks in advance
Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using either Gravity forms (PAID)  or the free CformsII

Here are links explaining the method on Gravity forms.

http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Merge_Tags